# How could I add multiple google tracking pixels in one page?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Please give a solution to add two analytics code in one page. i have to add to code in one page.How could I add multiple google  tracking pixels in one page?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this according to the documentation (
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers):

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker');